# How to measure face size in meters, centimeters or any units which is set?

Tags: modeling, units, measurement

How can I measure the size of a face in edit mode?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply tick *Length*  under *Mesh Display* in the *Properties* side panel and it will show the length of the edges (also tick *Area* to show the area if there are any faces). These measurements will use the unit specified under *Units* in your *Scene* settings. The shown units are local units and are scaled to world units by the object's Scaling settings (see also [Why do the measurements of this object seem erroneous?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous)).

[image: example measurement of a plane]

For something more extravagant, you can try the built-in [Ruler/Protactor](https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/grease_pencil/ruler_and_protractor.html) tool or Dolf's [Caliper addon](http://www.macouno.com/commissions/caliper/) (install and usage instructions on the page).

Comment: Good post as always :) Unfortunately the link to *Dolf's Calliper Add-on* is dead, I guess this is the right one: http://www.macouno.com/commissions/caliper/ ?

Comment: @poor thanks and yes it looks so. Feel free to update.