# Changing dimensions of a Child

Tags: modeling, dimensions

I have this sphere with dimensions and scale as below

[image]

How can I set the dimensions at x = 12.720m y = 12.756m and z = 12.756m and the scales at x = 0.997 y = 1.000 and z = 1.000

I have been trying with scale either Scale or Dimensions or typing in numbers but cannot get it right. I would think that changing dimensions and scale for an object should be very simple but this dumbo cannot get it done. How to do this ?

If I enter the number 12.756 in the X Dimensions field then Blender makes this

[image]

I simply don't get it.

After discussion with Rick it appeared that I had some modifiers attached to my object but the big problem appeared to be that my object was the child of another object and the parent did not allow to perform step one of Rick. After Clear Parent it was possible to Make Parent again but now with Keep Transformation, which let me perform transformations on the child without the parent interfering :)

Comment: Why do you want to have a scale that is not 1? I guess I don't understand your intentions. What I would do is set the dimensions to what I need then apply scale (Ctrl+A apply scale) to have the scale revert back to 1.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous/47320#47320

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Revised per chat conversation to get down to the real problem.**

The problem at its root had to do with a parent object relationship, and the sphere subordinate to this parent object was parented without the 'KEEP TRANSFORM' option. when this happens, the values begin to change in the scale of the subordinate, then the parent calculates what the subordinate should be and the subordinate changes its scale value automatically to adjust. So it became pretty unstable to adjust the values in the subordinate object.

To fix the root of the problem, we cleared the parent (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>), then reparented the subordinate back to its original parent (via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> >> Then clicked the 'Parent (keep transform)' option).

Then the rest of these steps worked in this scenario...

---

1. Change the dimensions to all be at full scale (12.756, 12.756, 12.756).
2. Then Apply the scale.
3. Then change your scale on X to 12.720/12.7560000000.

---

Appended per comments below:

[image]

(desired size) / (original size + 'appended zeros to go to the 10th decimal'), <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: And scale by X will be 12.718m. So this isn't precise.

Comment: if i enter the value 12.756 in the X dimension then Blender changes all dimensions . I will post an example

Comment: Use a little math in the scale factor. I'll show a screenshot in the answer.

Comment: the background of my question is this: i have three spheres ... the earth, the clouds and the atmosphere. and now I want to give those three sphere the proper dimensions in meters. I want the earth sphere something like 12.756 for all dimensions and the cloud sphere something bigger and the atmosphere again something bigger in meters. And I admit I have to study this Apply Scale ;)

Comment: so I want to set my earth sphere at 12.756m and scale 1.0 and the cloud sphere just something bigger (say scale 1.005)

Comment: I see your edit but my problem is to set the dimensions all at 12.756m and scale  = 1.0

Comment: You can think of applying the scale/rotation as just resetting the starting point. If I start with a 2x2x2 cube and scale it up by a factor of 2.0 then it is twice the size from when it started. Applying the scale in this case would say that I want to base my scale off of the new 4x4x4 dimension. which sets all of the scales to 1.0 but keeps the dimensions of the 4x4x4. So now to traverse back to 2x2x2 you would have to enter a factor of 0.5 (instead of 1.0 before applying the scale).

Comment: yes, but I want to create that starting point ... all dimensions 12.756 and scale  = 1.0. If I try to enter the value 12.756 in all dimensions Blender changes the values like above in my edit. I don't even get the chance to apply scale

Comment: I revised my answer, just follow steps 1 thru three exactly, make sure to follow step 3 according to the appended part of the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36244/discussion-between-jan-scherders-and-rick-riggs).