# Proportional individual inset

Tags: modeling

I've been following this tutorial:

youtube /watch?v=3jJGBzAxXKo

At the 5:10 mark, the guy insets multiple faces along individual origins at the same time to create windows.

His turn out proportional:
[image: good]
Mine do not:
[image: bad]
What am I doing wrong, and how do I get proportional windows like in the tutorial?

Comment: Have you tried hitting "I" (for Inset) twice?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous/47320#47320 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you object is not evenly scaled.

Exit *Edit Mode* and apply the scale to your object, by selecting it and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Scale*; then try doing the insets again.