# How can I extrude edges inwards so the offset distance is same for all edges?

Tags: extrude

How can I extrude edges inwards and keep same distance for all exuded edges? 
When I try to extrude (see pic 1) and press "s" all extruded edges have different offset from original (see pic 2) and I need extruded edges to have same offset distance from original. How can I do so?

[image: This is what I have]

[image: This is what I get]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50242/proportional-individual-inset/

Comment: As far as I know inset works only with faces. UPD. Nevermind I found out how to do it. Select vertices, press F, press I and move mouse a little to fit edges.