# Scaling so that the distances from the center are the same?

Tags: modeling

when I scale a face, it is scaled propotionally. But how can I scale it, so that the two distances that I marked here:

[image]

are the same?

thx

Comment: Inset (Shortcut: I).

Comment: Do you want the inside face to keep the same proportions between the two edges you circled or do you want the two edges to be of equal length?

Comment: Use the inset tool, but make sure you apply scale in edit mode before insetting. read: [why is it important to apply transformations to objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data) and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous/47320#47320

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50242/proportional-individual-inset/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52308/how-to-extrude-and-scale-with-an-even-offset/52315#52315

Comment: @Kiskit: I want the distance between the edges I circled tpo be the same (absolute9 value. When i inset or scale down it is scaled in a proportional way so the distanes will differ.

Comment: @cegaton: What you mean is apply scale in object mode, but this doesnt solve the problem.

Comment: Actually it seems to do the trick. Just tried with a brick, doesn't preserve distance with scale not applied, preserves with it applied.