# difference between dimension and scale in blender

Tags: modeling

First time in metric system and I can't figure out what is the dimension in blender, first of all the scale of a cube is one and the dimension is 2:
[image]
scaling the edge of only one edge up in edit mode turns up the dimension of the whole object to the size of the scale of the edge, and not the object in an average:
[image]

[image]

So, I'm a bit confused, about what the dimension in blender actually refer to, and what the difference between it and scale is?

EDIT:  What if the bounding box length and the edge are of equal size:
[image]

Comment: Somewhat related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous/47320#47320 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data

Answer (score 4):

Scale is a factor applied to an object non-destructively, on top of its true real
world dimensions. It doesn't really modify in underlying geometry or mesh data unless applied.

A 2 units cube with a scale of 2 will result in a total size of 4 units; a scale factor of 0.5 will result in a final size 1 unit. Scaling doesn't change the actual objects size, so if you enter *Edit Mode* on a cube with a scale factor of 2 its edges will still show dimensions with a perceived factor of 0.5 in relation to *Object Mode* because that is their true size.

Also see related [Why do the measurements of this object seem erroneous?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318)

Since scale is applied per object, several objects can share the same *objectdata* (shape defining geometry) but appear to have different sizes because each instance has a different scale factor, despite its geometry being the same and thus having the same true dimensions in *Edit Mode*.

Object dimensions are the result of the scale factor multiplied by the actual geometry size, and are measured relative to the size of its bounding box. If you change one edge size in *Edit Mode* it will change the cube's bounding box size, and hence its dimensions.

Comment: if we were to make a 2" edge then, we can't rely on the dimension panel then, better take it from the edge length?

Comment: You can always rely on the dimensions panel, it will always display the size of the bounding box. Now if that is the actual dimension you want to know or not is a another matter.

Comment: Why are the edge length and dimension showing unequal sizes when the bounding box length is equal to the edge length? (Please see my edit)

Comment: The dimensions panel is absolute measurements, the scale is relative

Comment: @BumbleBee if your scale is not applied the measurements in edit mode are not correct, they are relative to the scale of the object.

Comment: @cegaton, omitting the scale part, is the edge length also the absolute measurement of the length of an edge?(Please see my edit above)

Comment: only if the scale has been applied.

Comment: Please read the links: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous/47320#47320 AND http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data

Comment: @cegaton, Though I found it while doing, but, to confirm, does the dimension correspond to the local axes? And, also , changing the dimension would also change the scale, and to have accurate measurements, do we apply the scale from time to time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52178/discussion-between-cegaton-and-bumblebee).