# Dimension issue

Tags: dimensions

why for this hexagon to be symmetric, the x and y dimensions have to be 2,1 of difference?

[image: Symmetric hexagon]
If I enter the same value for both x and y, the hexagon looses its symmetry:

[image: The save value for x and y]
Rotating the hexagon, things results really weird:

[image: different distance from center]
If I rotate it in edit mode, everything goes messy:

[image: in edit mode goes messy]

Any ideas? Why do I have to make x and y 2,1 apart?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the Dimensions of an object, it is scaled to fit in a bounding box of the given size in the X, Y and Z of the object's local axes. (The XYZ of Object Space) The scale is not necessarily uniform.

A regular hexagon does not fit into a square. If it is 1 unit high, with corners top and bottom, it is sqrt(3) / 2 units wide.

So if you want to set the dimensions of the bounding box to contain a regular hexagon, height `H`, you would set the Y dimension to `H`, and the X dimension to `H*0.866`, which you can enter straight into the X field.

BTW, It's wise, (unless you have special reasons,) if you have scaled an object in Object Mode, to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Apply the scale of the object before proceeding, because of side-effects of non-uniform scaling in the object's transform on things like modifiers, further down the line.

Comment: Related: [Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data)

Comment: and : [Why do the measurements of this object seem erroneous?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous/47320#47320) and [difference between dimensions and scale in blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/difference-between-dimension-and-scale-in-blender?noredirect=1&lq=1)