# Why the dimension and edge length numbers does not tally when scaling objects?

Tags: transforms, edges, dimensions, measurement

I created a plane and set its dimensions to `32m x 4.5m`. When using the *edge length measurement tool*, it shows `1m` for every edge in the viewport.

[image]

[image]

**Q:** Why it doesn't display `32m x 4.5m` in the viewport?

Comment: This is due to the scale given in object mode. Apply scale Ctrl+A in object mode.

Comment: @lemon, thank you. noted.

I'm sorry but i don't understand the logic betwen the extra step...Kindly advice.

Is there any way to automatically make the edge follow the dimension by default?

Comment: If you scale in edit mode it will work properly right away.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [difference between dimension and scale in blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/difference-between-dimension-and-scale-in-blender)

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous/47320#47320 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data

Comment: Thank you hive mind. I have learnt a lot from the link you provided. Now i understand.