# height and scale units not equal

Tags: modeling, scale, units, measurement

So i made an object that is 2 meter wide and placed it 2m high on the z axis,
but compared to the grid in the background it is twice as long as the height of it.
What am i missing here?[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/difference-between-dimension-and-scale-in-blender  The original cube has dimensions 2 x 2 x 2 (units of lenght) and scale (1, 1, 1) (unit-less) Scaling by 2 on any original dimension makes it 2 x 2 = 4 as displayed in question image.

Comment: Scale is a simple multiplier to the actual dimension of any shape given. It defaults to 1 and it is also the reason you always have to "apply" scale transfomation after or the result will distort non-uniformly.

Comment: i think i found a way by pressing n and editing the dimension units. that should be the correct way right?