# First time using bevel tool, doesn't bevel evenly. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: bevel

First off I'll let you know I'm a total noob at blender I've used 3ds Max up until this point, but the company I'm working for at the moment needs me to use blender so I'm trying to make the transition over.

Literally all I'm making at the moment is a simple book and cannot understand how the bevel tool isn't working similar to how the chamfer tool would in 3ds Max.

I want a nice curved edge for the spine of the book however when I press <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and try to bevel it bevels the edge unevenly with the new bevel pushing forward.

[image: img]

Is there a way I can get it to bevel evenly like it does in Max?
[image: img]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your object has been scaled in object mode but the transformation has not been applied, so your mesh has a non-uniform scale that will prevent you from doing a clean bevel the way you want it.

Exit Edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and apply the scale (you can also use the menu: Object>Apply>Scale).

Back in edit mode the bevel should work evenly centered on the edge...

[image]

Comment: To understand more about applying transformations please red this related links: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html?highlight=apply%20transformations#apply and   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data/7967#7967 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous/47320#47320