# Why do symmetrically identical edges bevel differently?

Tags: bevel

[image]

I have a symmetrical object, the base of a column, and when I attempt to bevel the four corners of this object, each corner bevels by a different amount.

[image]

When I rotate the mesh about the z axis, the same edges continue to be beveled by the same inconsistent amount, so this difference has to be coming from the mesh somehow.

I can to some degree ameliorate the problem by deleting all but one of these edges and recreating the mesh by extruding and rotating by 90 degrees about the origin a few times. This greatly reduces the unevenness of the bevel, but not entirely.

Is the mesh just imperceptibly inaccurate, and if that's the case, why does such a small inaccuracy lead to such a large disparity in the bevel size?

[image]

Comment: Did you scale the object in edit mode? Did you apply scale? Read these related links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82515/first-time-using-bevel-tool-doesnt-bevel-evenly-what-am-i-doing-wrong and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23149/symetrical-bevel/23151#23151 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data

Comment: The object was never scaled in Object mode. Applying the scale has no effect on this beveling behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the options for he bevel operation (the toolbar or press <kbd>f6</kbd>) then you can change how the width is determined. In your case since the edges are equal length all around percent would work. I've noticed the bevel tool behaving weirdly as well (specifically when offset is used). Maybe it's a bug in the latest version of Blender.

Comment: Changing from 'Offset' to 'Width' seemed to solve the problem, so this is certainly enough of a workaround for now, though unfortunate because offset is usually what I care about in terms of how much I'm bevelling. Hopefully it is a bug, because if it isn't I sure don't understand the reasoning.