# Bevel doesn't work properly

Tags: bevel

i'm a beginner in Blender. I'm making a school assignment where i need to use the bevel. When i try to bevel a corner, instead of only rounding the corner, it goes further than only the corner i've selected. I'm using the normal shortcuts: ctrl + B and scrolling to get more segments. I've tried multiple times and i can't find a solution anywhere... 
Has anyone had this problem? 
Thanks :)
[image: Rectangle with beveled corner]
[image: Cube with beveled corner]

Comment: you need to apply the scale of your object in object mode (ctrl A)

Comment: I tried scaling the cube and than adding the bevel and that worked. However it doesn't work on the object that i need it to work on. The same thing keeps happening

Comment: could you post blend file?

Comment: do not scale your object, but apply the scale, which is another operation, it resets the object dimension: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82515/first-time-using-bevel-tool-doesnt-bevel-evenly-what-am-i-doing-wrong

Comment: Thank you that worked!!! Finally ! :)