# Create cut from the wall exactly 0.3m in

Tags: knife-tool

I have a 3d plane as the floor that's an odd shape.
I'm trying to create walls in from the side of exactly 0.3m.

Attempt 1 Use knife tool. This works but don't know how to set in from the edge exactly.

Attempt 2: Duplicate vertices, and just the override tool to set exactly.
Selected two outer vertices and duplicated, pressed x to move the vertices in and manually overrode them to be 0.3m in. This creates a separated edge from the original model. So I can't select a face to extrude.

Can someone point me in the right direction of how to do create a cut in from the edge of specific size? Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastest way seems to be the Bevel tool.

1. Select the starting edge and Bevel it
2. Set Segments = 2, Profile = 1
3. Adjust offset value to your 0,3 meters

*Note: This will also create two double verts. Select All and go Mesh > Clean Up > Merge by distance.*

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work, I like your thinking!.. The measurements are off though. They don't seem to match the global measurements not sure what going on.. I set the offset to 0.3m and it's much greater. So set it to 0.03 and it looks right, so I measured it and its about half the distance it's supposed to so it's still incorrect.. When I go to object mode the measure overall of the model seem to be correct. There must be a disparity between the object and editor mode in terms of scale? Sorry newbie stuff.

Comment: Yes, that's probably because of [non-uniform scale](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/82515/78972). Just apply scale and all operations will be precise :).

Comment: Thank you sir!! Perfect. That did the trick :)

Comment: Glad you made it work :). Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add walls to an already existing shape, use the inset (I) tool. Once activated you can enter an exact numerical value on the bottom left.

[image: Use the Inset Tool]

Additionally, if you only wanted to add one edge, you could turn on snapping (snap to edge), use Ctrl+R to add the edge/loop you want, manually move it (with snapping turned on) such that it overlaps with the edge you want to measure from, then invoke the move tool one more time and manually enter the distance you want it to travel.

[image: Use the move tool with snapping turned on]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is what I'm trying to achieve. I tried this approach and it does work but I'm getting issues with inaccurate sizing. Not clear what the issue is.. I set the wall thickness to 0.3 meters and it way bigger even though the overall object is accurate. I measured it after setting 0.3 and it says it's 1.3m.. if I set the thickness to 0.03 and measure it's 0.15m..

Comment: The issue was an non-uniform scale issue, see Jachym Michal comments above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the knife tool to make the initial cut, and then select the edge you created and move it to the edge of the face by pressing "G" twice. Then, with the edge still selected, you can move it along your axis of choice by pressing "G" and then the key for what axis you want to move it along, and then entering how far you want to move it (0.3 in your case).