# Why can't I set width and depth of a bevel?

Tags: bevel

I'm new to blender and I've gotten stuck trying to create a lozenge with rounded ends. Once edges are selected, I draw in the bevel but I cannot set the width of the new beveled ends. The bevel dialogue has a tab to set these but change width and it pulls the depth, change the depth and it pulls the width. Really annoying problem.

[image]

Comment: Make sure to apply scale to the object first (_Ctrl+A > Scale_ in object mode)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12288/why-are-the-longer-edges-being-beveled-more/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82515/first-time-using-bevel-tool-doesnt-bevel-evenly-what-am-i-doing-wrong