# Is it possible to lock the scale when entering dimensions?

Tags: units, dimensions

I have a Grid Floor with an area of one square kilometer and an origin at (0,0,0).

I would like to add a wireframe cube centered at (0,0,0) with a with dimensions 250 m by 250 m by 250 m.

On the Transform panel, when I lock the Location at (0,0,0) and lock the Scale at (1,1,1) and set the dimensions, the scale; although locked changes to (250,250,250).

Is there any way to lock the scale at (1,1,1)?

Comment: related:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous/47320#47320 and  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data

Comment: You cannot do that, changing dimensions works specifically by changing the scale, if you blocked it changing the dimensions would not work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two alternatives:

Scale your object in **Object Mode** as you describe, and then **Apply** the scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>). Your object will then have the correct dimensions and the scale will be reset to 1,1,1

As an alternative create your object and do all of the scaling in **Edit Mode**, that will not affect the scale of the object.