# Object measurements are not the same

Tags: dimensions

I am using Blender 2.79 and appended an object into the view port and its dimensions are all wrong. I am using feet for my units and made a cube that was 9 feet tall which gives the correct dimensions but the other appended object of the same height is shown as 1.83 feet tall and 62 ft on the x axis when in reality it is only 1 foot.  I tried resetting the scale but it did not help. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: It is likely that the appended object does not have scaling applied to it. Read: [Why do the measurements of this object seem erroneous?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous/47320#473200)

Comment: Thanks before I posted I found this link you gave me and had already applied scale to the object but it did not change the dimensions. I had made a pillar in meters in another file and when it was appended to my new scene it came out at 62 Ft. on the X axis and 9.3 ft. on the Y axis and then 1.83 ft. on the Z axis. IF these measures are correct this would be a very strange pillar. Ha This object should be 9 ft. on the Z and 1 ft. both on the Y&X axis which it is when compared to a cube of the same size.  A little confusing when trying to proceed. I might have to make a new pillar.