# How to make walls with the same thickness?

Tags: modeling

I m noob in modeling and I have one problem with thickness walls of my shopping bag.

[image]

I wanna make walls the same thickness, actually I can't do this using E (External) or Solidify modifier. It doesn't work.

[image]

Every distance is different size, can you help me fix it ?

Comment: you can click the Even Thickness option in the Solidify modifier

Comment: I doesn't work. try it.

Comment: When something doesn't work state clearly *what* doesn't work as you expect and show more screenshots / description instead of continous repeating "doesnt work"

Comment: Read: [Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data) and [Why do the measurements of this object seem erroneous?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous/47320#47320)

Answer (score 5):

You have uneven scales on all axis (yellow marker). this happens when you scale your object in Object mode.

[image]

press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>A</kbd>  and select **Scale** in object mode. That should fix your problem.

Comment: It doesn't work. I do this in edit mode and scaling give the same effect.

Comment: so you have both applied the scale + click the Even Thickness Option?

Comment: in Edit mode you can Extrude then Enter right away, now you press alt S and chose the thickness

Comment: Try it with Thickness option, the same problem.

Comment: Extrude I try and ... if I use Extrude with region vertexs normal  or Extrude region and after alt + s its the same problem

Comment: Go out of edit mode and press CTRL + A -> Apply Scale. If this doesn't work (it should work) you can upload your .blend-file and I'll have a look.

Comment: YEAH, CTRL + A fixed problem, you are awesome, thx.

Comment: well... that's what we told you, apply scale