# Why do measurements change when switching from Global to Local in edit mode?

Tags: modeling, mesh, interface, edges, units

Why does the edge length information shown after ticking Edge Info -> Edge Length under Mesh Display change after choosing Global or Local?

[image]

Comment: 2.76 is quite old, upgrade to a newer version. Edge length in Global coordinates depends on a lot of things like object scale, modifiers, deformations applied among others.

Comment: Related: [Why do the measurements of this object seem erroneous?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous/47320#47320)

Answer (score 1):

When you are using **Local**, you are looking at the dimensions **relative to the scaling** of the object (if scaled in object mode).

**Global** will show you the **absolute** measurements.

As an example. Here's a cube that has been scaled 2 times in the $Z$ axis.

[image]

If you switch between local and global coordinates in edit mode.

The measurements in local units are relative to the scaling and show that the cube is 2x2x2, whereas the Global units show the absolute measurements showing that the cube is no longer a cube, but a cuboid that is 4m tall.

[image]

---

**Why should you care for local or global measurements?**

Please read: [Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data)

Answer (score 0):

Global is based on the 'World' coordinates (0,0) where 'Local' is relative to its self, which could be anywhere in 'World' space. [hope i got that right].