# Dimension vs scale

Tags: modeling

I'm creating a sofa in blender and working in inches. If I create a seat cushion 24x24x4 and this shows in the properties panel (N) dimensions, why do the values in the SCALE for x,y&z change - apparently to half that of my x,y&z dimensions?

Comment: I don't know how to measure my object to see if my object is equal to the dimension values or the scale values.

Comment: Somewhere along the line you have scaled your cushion in Object mode. Now to set the scale back to 1 in all three axis you need to apply the scale. To do that, in Object mode, with your cushion selected hit the keyboard shortcut Ctrl A to open the Apply menu and choose the Scale option. Now your cushion will truly measure 24 x 24 x 4 :) .

Comment: Related [why do the measurements seem erroneous?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous/47320#47320) and [Why do measurements change when switching to local in edit mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/103257/why-do-measurements-change-when-switching-from-global-to-local-in-edit-mode/103259#103259) and [why is it important to apply transformations to an objects data](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data)

Answer (score 0):

Dimensions are the actual size of your mesh. Scale is the object's size relative to its base size.

For example, if you took a 2x2x2 cube, its dimensions would be 2x2x2 and its scale would be [1, 1, 1]. If you double the size of the cube, the dimensions are now 4x4x4 and the scale is [2, 2, 2] since 4x4x4 (the object's current size) is double the volume of 2x2x2 (the object's base size).

To answer your question, your scale is probably different because you scaled it in object mode (as 3fingeredfrog said in the OP's comments). To make it [1, 1, 1] scale while maintaining the dimensions, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and select Scale. Tada!

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Sounds like I can just ignore the changing scale as long as my object dimensions are correct.

Comment: @b0rdrgrl Well, you really should try to keep the scale [1,1,1] in the end because when you do certain operations (such as UV unwrapping) with a non-[1,1,1] scale, it gets weird.