# How to get Accurate Scaling When Making New Objects?

Tags: objects, transforms, scale, units

I seem to be running into an issue with creating new objects? Could someone please help me?

### **The Set Up**

I am building a packaging mock up, that requires multiple boxes that slide together. the new object slides into / out of the old object. So Eventually these will be animated (Very New to Allot of This)

### **The Question**

As per my images below, Both outer object and inner object have been set to the same size yet they visually appear two different sizes? The "Old Object" is created from the original default cube as per my memory. The second object is per a new added cube (1mm). How can I get an accurate scale?

Any help on this would be much appreciated. I am learning allot of new skills with this project and very open to new avenues in thinking about 3D development.

Thank you.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Scale is a multiplier that is applied to the local size of the mesh to calculate the global size and the dimensions of the object. This is not what you want.

You're probably looking for the dimensions of the object or better the edge lengths of the mesh.

In `Object Mode`, you can see and edit the dimensions of the object in the sidebar ("N-panel", press <kbd>N</kbd> in the view to open it). With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then Apply Scale you can apply the scale, what resets it to 1. See here: [Dimension vs scale](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/132793/107598)

In `Edit Mode`, you can display the lengths of the edges. You need to activate it in the Overlays drop-down menu. There you can switch between Global and Local and you will see the impact of the scale. Have a look here for screenshots: [Why do measurements change when switching from Global to Local in edit mode?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/103257/107598)