# Objects are 2 different sizes but scale says they're the same

Tags: armature, scale

While trying to make my dude I had to scale him up so he would align with the reference image I'm using. But the little box that shows his size and position says hes 2.202 (on all axes) , while the armature that is also 2.202 is smaller.

If I scale the armature it comes out at the wrong size, and if I apply scale to the character he will just be the same size except the scale is reset to 1.

I really don't want to recreate the armature since getting his finger bones was an absolute pain ☹️.

Here are images of the said things.

[image: Dude and his armature]

[image: The dudes scale]

[image: The armatures scale]

Comment: ok I guess i will change it...

Comment: Read: [why do measurements change when switching from global to local in edit mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/103257/why-do-measurements-change-when-switching-from-global-to-local-in-edit-mode/103259#103259) and [Why do the measurements of this object seem erroneous?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous/47320#47320)

Comment: As a beginner, I didn't get why strange things were happening, until I discovered Object | Apply | Rotation and Scale.  It then became my "goto" thing for fixing up weird problems.  In about 99% of times, it does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, object scale and Edit Mode scale are two different things. You likely scaled him in Edit Mode, so the object mode scale does not change. I would scale one of the two objects back down in Edit Mode (`Tab`) until they match up. Hope this helps!

Comment: ok I resized it a bit and I guess i got it the correct size.