# How to figure "Array" modifier offset when using "Subdivision" modifier as well?

Tags: modifiers, measurement

First of all, I’ve seen how using the Subdivision Surface modifier on a cylinder will shrink the radius.  But, the Transform pane shows the actual, new dimensions, so it’s easy to fix:  type the correct dimension again in the box.  In my case, this scaled up by 1.108.

Now, make an Array of those.  The center-to-center [spacing is 8mm](http://orionrobots.co.uk/wiki/lego_specifications.html), but using that in the “Constant Offset” field gives a displacement that is too large!  Using the measuring tool and just fiddling with the value, I found that ≈7.22 mm gives the correct result.

Where is this number coming from?  Since the focal point of the original object is in the center, the scaling up should not change the offset, which is the center-to-center distance.  Even if the scale (1.108) did show up somehow, I don’t see how that can result in the value obtained.

So, how exactly is the “Constant Offset” figured?

---

P.S. The order of the modifiers does not matter.

[image: Lego brick in progress]

Comment: Did you scale in Edit mode or in Object mode. If you scaled in Object mode, did you "apply" the scale? Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous/47320#47320

Comment: @cegaton, the scale was "applied" to give the correct dimensions of the faceted cylinder.  Then, the final correction to fix the diameter based on “Subdivision” is left in place.  This does not seem to be the same as the referenced question:  the measurement lines (general measure tool, not face measure) are accurate; the post’s dimensions in the transform box show the final thing that is rendered, including the scale and the effects of the modifier.  IAC, I don’t find the scale value (1.108) to be in any way related to the fudge factor.