# Why there is difference in the measurement

Tags: measurement

With the Measure tool i have draw the line to measure the model. It shows 6.03. Where as in the N panel under dimensions in the z axis it shows 5.18. Why there is difference in the measurement

[image]

I tried to scale the complete model but some parts disappear.

[image]

Any solution to get perfect measurement for the model.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous

Comment: @susu But when i apply rotation scale. Some mesh disappear

Comment: @vklidu. My question is related to each other and its not 2 questions. After scale the mesh disappear.

Comment: please share your file

Comment: @atek Sorry, you are right, it wasn't Q. My I ask you to delete second image anyway, it would be easier for followers. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Measurments differs because **Dimension displays size of Active object only**.
With *Measurment Tool* you measure all objects.

Comment: Well spotted. it's much simpler than the comments think !