# Ruler/protractor reports doubled measure

Tags: measurement

Blender 2.79.

I draw a cube entering the measures manually as scale values.

Then if I select the Ruler/Protractor tool, I see a measure that is the double value against the entered value.

Why?

Comment: Read: 
[Why do the measurements seem erroneous](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous)

Comment: Hello, SteMMo, the comments are on to it. The Object-Mode transforms scale the objedt; the 'vehicle' of the mesh, not the mesh itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scales values aren't dimensions. Scale works as a factor of the object's original dimensions.

I.E if you look at the default cube, its scales are 1:1:1, but if you look at its dimensions: 2:2:2.

If you set the scale at 2, the dimensions will be 4:4:4. If you set the sclaes to 0.5, dimensions will be 1:1:1.

Comment: Oh my, you are right but I'm using scales cause I'm not able to find the dimensions values ..

Comment: They are displayed in the sidebar, just bellow the scale values if I remember well.