# measurement doesn't match

Tags: scale, measurement

I'm pretty new to blender. I can't explain what's happenin, but look. Visualy longer edge is (according to blender) much shorter (83mm) than visualy shorter edge(4628mm).

What may be helpful is that edges belong to different meshes and that in front was copy pasted from another .blend file.

The project is for 3D printing and I would like to avoid problems with measurement.

Thanks in advance.
Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Try resetting the scale (in object mode, select the object and press CTRL + A, then select scale)

Comment: Thanks! You're right, the answer is exactly here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous

Comment: Sory I cant delete question :(