# Why is size different in Measure than in Transform

Tags: transforms

I am designing element to 3D print. I want sizes to be equal on x and y axes, like a circle or pipe so to say. This is what one can see when I place the points, the correct and desired distance is show, but on the transform screen, you can see the size to be different. Which is really weird I think.
[image: Image of Blender Screen]
(Context, i created this image by doing the boolear operator between a cylinder, two pipes, and straight borders to create the holes in every 90 degrees. )

The given sizes are also not logical, because I see the pipe to be circular in the render, but it says that X is 6.77 cm and that Y is 3.84 cm. But it gets shown equal.

This is the file if you want to check it out: [image]

What can I do, so that my object also gets shown the sizes on the transform screen, which sizes are the incorrect ones.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Although here was also a problem with the scale, applying it will not fully get rid of the incorrect dimensions because of the additional invisible vertex (see my answer), so the linked duplicate question provides no sufficient solution. It wouldn't make sense editing the answer there either since there is no additional vertex causing problems.

Comment: True, reopened. I was under the wrong impression Blender discarded wire geometry from object dimensions.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object has a single vertex a bit off the mesh - the dimensions show the size of the object's bounding box which contains this vertex. Since it is a single vertex not connected to the rest of the mesh, you can't see in *Object Mode* and in *Edit Mode* only when switching to *Vertex Select*.

[image: hidden vertex]

The other thing is you didn't apply the scale. So even when you get rid of the vertex, the dimensions shown in *Object Mode* will not match the measurements shown in *Edit Mode*. *Object Mode* shows the real world dimensions while *Edit Mode* shows the edge length at original size which is when the object is scaled to 1/1/1 on XYZ. Your object is 1.05 on X/Y and 1.5 on Z.

To make the real world dimensions match the measurements, you have to apply the scale by selecting the object, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and choose *Apply* > *Scale*. This sets XYZ scale to 1 while keeping the current dimensions.

[image: apply scale]

Comment: Thank you very much. It is solved.

Comment: @Flavio Maybe you want to consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem?