# Place objects in an obj scene, with real dimensions

Tags: dimensions

I've got a mesh of my living room and I'm trying to add some furnitures in the scene, in a very basic way: a furniture is represented as a box.

But I want to have exact proportions for each furniture of course at the main idea is to see how it'd look like, the space it'd take etc etc.

Disclaimer: I've never used Blender before. I have played a little with Onshape but that it for my super limited knownledge in 3D world.

That said, it sounds like something that should be trivial:

- Import an obj
- Define a scale based on 1 measurement you know in the scene
- Whenever you add a cube, 1 unit should represent 1m for example

I have looked into several tutorials and [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47320/161733) but for some reason I can't get it to behave as I'd expect. I have tried creating a box of width X, along a line in the scene that I know has a length of X. I thought everything would be easy from there having scaled my mesh based on a cube. But nop, I always get weird results after.

Could someone explain a step by step guide of how to achieve this please? Thanks for any help

Comment: It's really hard to guess what that 'some reason' might be in "for some reason I can't get it to behave as I'd expect" so I think it might make sense for you to just watch some tutorials for basics. Other way someone must provide all that info for you in an answer here in order to provide you with meaningful help and that's just not really practical. Tutorials will be way more effective. You can find some really good ones to start with on [Blender's website](https://www.blender.org/support/tutorials/)

Comment: Makes sense. I'll definitely try to learn the basics properly! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender is set up to use meters as default units:

[image]

You should make sure these settings are the same in your scene and that is pretty much it.

Whenever you create an object, you can see its dimensions in the Sidebar(also often called 'n panel', because it can be opened and closed hitting <kbd>n</kbd>) :

[image]

Active object will get scaled to them if you adjust them.

Blender uses default scene units everywhere, so for example if you hit <kbd>g</kbd> for grab and enter translate operation, then constrain the operation in some axis (<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd>) and enter some numeric value, it will be in meters and your object(or selected element in edit mode) will get moved that distance. Other operations also use the units, so if you wanted to make a bevel with radius of 2mm for example, you could enter bevel operation and type 0.002:

[image]

You can also enter units in all numerical input fields in Blender and they will be automatically converted to scene's default units for you:

[image]

You can also do this with numerical input while in various operations, but you need to enter advanced input mode by hitting <kbd>Numpdad *</kbd> first.

So everything is already in real units in Blender by default and you don't usually need to do anything. It's only a matter of scaling and modelling your objects to sizes you wish them to be.

Comment: Thank you so much the perfect answer! I had the default panel on the right with location, rotation and scale but dimensions where not there so I was messing around with the scale and even if I applied it... It was not working properly. As you mentioned, pressing N brought the same panel BUT it also had the dimensions which worked perfectly! Thank you so much.

Comment: If I can add one more question that is related though: My mesh of my living room has a given size. I know within the mesh, the distance between 2 points. Is there a way to say in Blender: "I know the distance between this point and this one, scale the rest of the mesh accordingly"? What I did was put a box of the given dimension between the 2 point and then rescale the mesh of the living room until it looked like it was fitting perfectly with the box. It worked but I know it's far from ideal. If that deserves an entire new question, do let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, just ask a new question. You need to make something with that distance and then snap one of the points using snapping functionality with scale. I cant explain that in a comment.

Comment: Done! https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/285105/scale-a-mesh-based-on-a-measure-defined-in-that-mesh