# How can I scale a mesh based on known distance between its vertices?

Tags: measurement

I've got a mesh representing my living room. I built the mesh using [Meshroom](https://github.com/alicevision/Meshroom). I ended up with a few things around the bit of my living room I'm interested in.

I want to scale the entire mesh to the real world dimensions, but I do not know the exact dimensions of the bounding box of the mesh. I only know the distance between two points in the mesh. Is there a way to say "I know a distance between these two points in the mesh, scale the rest of the mesh accordingly to have real world measurements"?

Here's how the mesh looks (it's only one mesh) and the measurement I know:

[image]

Because the mesh was built using Meshroom, you can see the points cloud, and I don't have one edge that I can easily select, so I shall be able to define the length between two points, at the start and end of my red line above. Here's the mesh in edit mode to get an idea:

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly you have there? In Blender, meshes are usually the vertices that build the edges and faces of a mesh object. A living room can have several objects and each object has its own mesh. So, do you have "a mesh" = 1 mesh object, or do you just call the sum of all objects together "a mesh" = a scene filled with several mesh objects?

Comment: But anyway, I will assume the scene is filled with many objects. Let's say you have one single edge and you know it's 1 m in real life. Click to select the object containing that edge. Then press Tab to go into _Edit Mode_, select that 1 m edge. Activate _Edge Length_ in the _Overlays_. If the length in the model is for example 0.25 m, then Tab again to go back to _Object Mode_, select all objects with A, then scale them by factor 4 (because 1 m / 0.25 m = 4) by pressing S, 4, Return. Of course this works with other factors as well, also with decimals.

Comment: I just added some more details, hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since we now know that you are talking about a single mesh with a lot of vertices, you can do it a bit different as I explained in the comments on my other answer.

Let's say you have a dense mesh and you know the distance between two of those points (I'll take a generated landscape because I have no other dense mesh right now). First make sure the *Scale* of the mesh object is 1 on all axes in *Object Mode*:

[image: scale at 1]

Then <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode*, select the two points of which you know the distance:

[image: select known distance]

Hit <kbd>F</kbd> to create a new edge between them. Activate *Edge Length* in the *Overlays* for the viewport. In my case it shows the length of the edge as 1.2 m:

[image: display edge length]

This value might not be precise enough for scaling the object to its real world measurements, depending on how precise you want it. You can go to *Scene Properties* > *Units* and change the unit for *Length* to *Millimeters* or *Micrometers* instead of *Meters*. Now the length shows 1196469 μm = 1.196469 m which is a bit more precise.

[image: change units for precision]

If you have noted the value somewhere, you don't need the edge any longer and can delete it with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete* > *Edges* (not *Vertices*!). But you can do it after the scaling as well. If you keep it now, you can use it for checking the distance afterwards.

<kbd>Tab</kbd> back into *Object Mode*. With the known real distance between the vertices and the measured length of the edge, you can calculate the scaling factor by dividing them:

$$\frac{\text{real distance}}{\text{measured length}}=\frac{\text{5 m}}{\text{1.196469 m}}\approx4.178963$$

Now in *Object Mode* simply enter the value into the *Scale* for the object, you can do it separately for X, Y and Z or drag over the three fields to enter the same value in all fields at once, then hit <kbd>Return</kbd> to confirm the new scale:

[image: set new scale]

The last thing to do is applying the scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply* > *Scale*  or else the measurement in *Edit Mode* would still show 1.2 m:

[image: apply scale]

But with the scale applied it now shows 5000001 μm which is almost perfect. By now you can definitely delete the edge and set the length unit back to *Meters*, *Millimeters* or whatever you want.

[image: new edge length]

**Bonus tip:**

In a very dense mesh it can be very hard to see the newly created edge and the displayed length:

[image: dense crowded mesh]

To make it easier to see them, you can - with the vertices needed for measurement selected (even before creating the new edge) - press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to hide all unselected vertices and you can now see the edge and the length better (or you create the edge now with <kbd>F</kbd> if you haven't done before):

[image: hide all unselected vertices]

To get the hidden vertices back, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. If you disable the checkbox *Select* in the *Reveal Hidden* option at the bottom left, you avoid having all other vertices now selected so that only the new edge will be selected still (helps with deleting it afterwards). Although there is no need to reveal the vertices before scaling and deleting the new edge, since hiding them does not affect the scale operation in *Object Mode*.

[image: reveal hidden vertcies]

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed explanation, that's brilliant

Answer (score 4):

Here's a *Geometry Nodes* solution (for a single mesh):

Enter into *Edit Mode*, select two vertices you know the distance between, and hit <kbd>Ctrl + G</kbd> to create a vertex group out of them. By default, the name of the vertex group will be "*Group*". In the Geometry Nodes modifier we use two `Sample Index` nodes, one set to index $0$ and the other $1$ to get the positions of those two vertices. A `Vector Math` gets the *Distance* between them, then the whole geometry gets scaled (`Transform Geometry`) by the ratio of the real measurement to the current. Finally, a `Remove Named Attribute` makes sure the vertex group we only created for this purpose gets deleted when you apply the modifier:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could duplicate one of the vertices you know distance between and force it to be the correct distance, then scale everything from the first vertex snapping the second one to the new one you just made:

[image]

You would need to set up the snapping to work for that. I use 3d Cursor snapped to the first vertex as pivot point for the transformation. It needs to be set appropriately:

[image]

I snapped it to the vertex with the snap menu - Shift + S.

Since my points are on the same X axis, I could simply move my duplicate constraining the transform operation in X axis, however if it's not the case, you might need to make a custom transform orientation from the selected vertices:

[image]

If you make a custom transform orientation from an edge(that happens if unconnected 2 vertices are selected as well), Y is the axis along the edge(or the imaginary edge that would connect the 2 vertices), so you hit Y to constrain transform operations in that direction. This is only for moving the vert, you probably want the object scaled in all direction, so no need to do anything for scaling.

Snapping can be turned on temporarily holding ctrl key down while in transform operation, but you could just turn it on fully as well:

[image]

In my example the transform operation uses 3d Cursor as its pivot point, but the snap target is set to active element that is the vertex I made sure to select last. Snapping options are set here:

[image]

Comment: This is done using 2 vertices that seem to be on the bounding box, could you do the same from let say the 2 eyes. If you know the distance between the 2 eyes is 1m. Would the same apply? And how did you get the measurement initially? When it starts it already displays 70

Comment: I've edit my original post to add more info in case it's of any help!

Comment: It doesn't matter where the vertices are.

Comment: @maxime1992 He didn't get any measurements there. That is simply a mesh in the shape of "70 cm" as you can see from the vertices in the third screenshot. He wanted to illustrate that this edge is supposed to have a length of 70 cm in reality. Or when you import a CAD drawing it could be that you have the written measurements as mesh in there, too.

Comment: *facepalm* yup makes sense, cheers! Newbie with blender, I think you figured it out! But nevertheless you guys helped me achieve what I needed, thanks a lot for your patience!

Answer (score 3):

Let's say I have a room like this, consisting of several objects. But I know it has not the original size.

[image: room overview]

But I know for example how high the edge of the wall is from floor to ceiling. It doesn't matter which edge size you know, this is just an example that can be used for other parts of the room as well. So, I select the wall object, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go into *Edit Mode*, select the wall edge and enable the *Edge Length* in the *Overlays*. This shows a height of 1.24 m:

[image: room height edge length]

But I don't think this value is precise enough for my taste, as a little trick I go to *Scene Properties* > *Units* and set the *Length* from *Meters* to *Micrometers*. Now the edge shows a length of 1237205 μm:

[image: length in micrometers]

Now I know that the height of the room is 2.5 m so with 1237205 μm or 1.237205 m I get a scaling factor of around

$$\frac{2.5 m}{1.237205 m}=2.0206837...$$

So I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go back into *Object Mode*, select all objects with <kbd>A</kbd>. Now it is important that the *Pivot Point* for the transformation is not set to *Individual Origins*. Any other will be okay and depends on if you want the room to stay in place with one of its corners for example, then you could set the 3D cursor there and use it as pivot point. In this example I just use the *Median Point*.

[image: pivot point]

Now I'm scaling all objects at once by the calculated factor by pressing the scale shortcut followed by the numbers: <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>2.0206837</kbd> <kbd>Return</kbd>.

[image: scaling by factor]

To make the new size the original size of the objects, apply the scale while all objects are still selected with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply* > *Scale*.

[image: apply scale]

Switching the wall object back into *Edit Mode* the selected edge now shows a length of 2500 mm (I've switched to Millimeters because I don't need the Micrometers precision anymore).

[image: new edge length]

Comment: Thanks! This looks like the simpler answer so far, I'll go with that!

Comment: Actually sorry, I mark as answered too quickly. In my case the mesh ic composed of plenty of points, I don't have a single edge I can select. But I'll remember that, still super interesting thanks!

Comment: @maxime1992 Oh I see. You could also create a temporary edge. Select the first and last vertex of the distance you know and hit F. This connects them with an edge and you have the length. Then hit X > _Delete_ > _Edges_ to get rid of it afterwards.

Comment: I just edited my post with more info, I think it'll make more sense why I said that in my case your solution wouldn't work :)

Comment: @maxime1992 Maybe the comment I gave while you edited the answer helps 

Comment: Interesting! I tried selecting 2 vertices with control + click and hit F but nothing seems to happen when I hit F. Is it supposed to pop a panel as well? Or what should I do exactly after hitting F?

Comment: @maxime1992 You need Shift+Click to select them both...

Comment: Yes sorry I meant shift. I can see they're selected as they're orange but pressing F once I've got both selected doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: @maxime1992 Hmmm... is the mesh too dense so that the edge is hard to see? This should work. What happens if you select both, hit Shift+H (hides all unselected, only the two should be visible now) and then hit F?

Comment: Oh ok so I did what you said, I can see both points and the edge now. But if I hit N to get the panel where I can define the size, it's different than when I select the mesh, I can't set the size there. How do I proceed from there to set the length? Oh and how do I revert the Shift H? I tried doing it again but it only shows the 2 points and the edge now

Comment: @maxime1992 I don't set the size in the N panel anywhere in my answer...? Unhiding is done by Alt+H

Answer (score 2):

I do this quite a lot for reference images and imported vector drawings, so I wrote a little add-on to make my life easier. Since I already made it, I thought I could share it here.

It's in Transform sub menu in Object and Mesh(in Edit mode) menus in the 3d viewport header or you can just search for it with <kbd>F3</kbd>. You have to have 2 vertices selected(doesn't matter if you leave edit mode). It scales <strike>the object</strike> all selected objects without applying scale.

[image]

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Scale By Known Distance",
    "author": "Martynas Žiemys",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (3, 5, 1),
    "location": "View3D search -> Scale By Known Distance, View3D -> Object -> Transform / Mesh -> Mransform",
    "description": "Scales mesh by known distance between 2 vertices",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "Object",
}

import bpy, math
from bpy.props import FloatProperty

class OBJECT_OT_scale_by_known_distance(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.scale_by_known_distance"
    bl_label = "Scale By Known Distance "
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    l : FloatProperty(name = "Distance between vertices: ", default = 0)
    current_distance = 0
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object.type == 'MESH'

    def execute(self, context):
        o = bpy.context.object
#        sel = [v for v in o.data.vertices if v.select]
#        o.scale = o.scale * self.l / self.current_distance 
#        o.update_from_editmode()

# Probably more usefull to scale all selected objects
        scale = self.l / self.current_distance 
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
        saved_pivot = bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.transform_pivot_point
        bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.transform_pivot_point = 'ACTIVE_ELEMENT'
        bpy.ops.transform.resize(value = (scale,scale,scale))
        bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.transform_pivot_point = saved_pivot
        self.report({"INFO"}, str(scale))
        self.report({"INFO"},"Scaled from " + str(self.current_distance) + " to " + str(self.current_distance*scale) + " ( " + str(scale) + " ) ")
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        o = bpy.context.object
        o.update_from_editmode()
        sel = [v for v in o.data.vertices if v.select]
        if len(sel) == 2:
            self.current_distance = self.l = math.dist(o.matrix_world @ sel[0].co, o.matrix_world @ sel[1].co)
            return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self, width = 450)
        else:
            self.report({"WARNING"}, "Select 2 vertices!")
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        
def add_scale_by_known_distance_button(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(OBJECT_OT_scale_by_known_distance.bl_idname, icon='PLUGIN')
        

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_scale_by_known_distance)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_transform_object.append(add_scale_by_known_distance_button)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_transform.append(add_scale_by_known_distance_button)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_scale_by_known_distance)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_transform_object.remove(add_scale_by_known_distance_button)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_transform.remove(add_scale_by_known_distance_button)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

So that's to be pasted into a text document(just use Blender's Editor to be sure about correct encoding) and saved to a file with .py extension. It can then be installed as any add-on from User Preferences(<kbd>F4</kbd> -> <kbd>P</kbd> -> Add-ons tab)

Comment: This looks awesome! Thanks for sharing!